# scala merge two or more string as an array in one json property

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a lot of json string lines in many files and they have like:

```
{ "id":123, "team":"A", "etc":"...", ...}
{ "id":124, "team":"A", "etc":"...", ...}
{ "id":124, "team":"B", "etc":"...", ...}
{ "id":125, "team":"A", "etc":"...", ...}
```

I can load them as DataFrame in scala.

By grouping by id, I want to get like:

```
{ "id":123, "team":"A", "etc":"...", ...}
{ "id":124, "team":["A","B"], "etc":"...", ...}
{ "id":125, "team":"A", "etc":"...", ...}
```

In scala, how can I do this?

NOTE: I don't know how many sub-properties are in each json. Most properties are common across json lines. But it is possible to have a few unique properties in a few json lines.

Comment: do you want to do this in apache-spark?

Comment: Yes! apache-spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to group by id and collect each individual columns as lists?

**Updated** to use a dynamic list of columns:

```
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [etc: string, id: bigint ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+---+---+----+
|etc| id|team|
+---+---+----+
|  X|123|   A|
|  Y|124|   A|
|  Z|124|   B|
|  X|125|   A|
+---+---+----+

val grpCol = "id"
val collectCols = (df.columns.toSet - grpCol).map(c => collect_list(c).as(c)).toSeq

df.groupBy('id).agg(collectCols.head, collectCols.tail: _*).show

+---+------+------+
| id|   etc|  team|
+---+------+------+
|124|[Y, Z]|[A, B]|
|123|   [X]|   [A]|
|125|   [X]|   [A]|
+---+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you. However, still one more problem. I don't know how many the other columns will come. Is there any smart way to call collect_list() for uncertain number of columns?

Comment: Updated to use a dynamic list of columns.